# NGRX - Refetch data from endpoint with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am working with an ngrx effect to fetch data from an API endpoint and add to the state. From time to time, a user action may invalidate this data and it would need re-fetching from the database.

### Current Behaviour

1. Action triggered to fetch data and add to state store. A new XHR request is recorded in the network fetching the data.
2. User takes an action on the frontend, and a re-fetch is required.
3. NGRX action `GET_KITS` is dispatched and the action is logged to DevTools.
4. No new XHR request is made. No update is made to the store.

### Desired Behaviour

4. New request is made to fetch the latest data from the API.

#### Effects

```
getUserKits$ = createEffect(
    () =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(UserActions.AccountKitActions.GET_KITS.type),
            switchMap(() => this.kitService.getKits()
                .pipe(
                    map(response => UserActions.AccountKitActions.GET_KITS_SUCCESS({kits: response.data.kits})),
                    catchError((err: GraphQLError) => {
                        return of(UserActions.AccountKitActions.GET_KITS_FAIL());
                    })
                )
            )
        )
)
```

The action is dispatched as follows:

```
this.store.dispatch(AccountKitActions.GET_KITS());
```

Comment: Not sure if I get this, so if the user doesn't invalidate the data, the app doesn't make an HTTP call right? then why not just fetch it again even if the user didn't invalidate the data...

Comment: Dispatching the action doesn't make a new HTTP request beyond the first time. It only fetches once (the first time the action is dispatched and the effect called). The next time the action is dispatched, a new request is not called

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see is the .type doesn't need to be on the action on the ofType.  Though you say it works the first time through, which is surprising.

```
ofType(UserActions.AccountKitActions.GET_KITS),
```

Early on in my ngrx journey, I often found adding tap operators with a console.log of the parameters helped to determine how the flow was actually occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did actually try this as a 'lets just see' and it made no difference. The issue just seems to be that once it has been subscribed to, it isn't easy to re-fetch fresh ata through the same request or by terminating the current subscription and making a new one.